# Date time Comparison

Tags: php, sql

I am using php to save Time and date in database. My Data Time Format is 12/02/2016 1:30 PM.

I want to compare this with present time. I have user following query

```
("SELECT * FROM content WHERE catid='8' AND futureEntry < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%e %d %Y %h:%i %p') AND expiringEntry < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%e %d %Y %h:%i %p')" )
```

but this condition is not working. Please help me with a suitable solution thanks in advance. NT: my present time is smaller yet it's returning multiple row

Comment: what is the column datatype in db

Comment: is there any error in you query
else DATE_FORMAT(NOW()) will take the mysql server time ie the current date of you server

Comment: There is no error in my query and field futureEntry and expiringEntry are varchar(50)

Comment: You're comparing a value type DATETIME to a column with type varchar(50)

Comment: Am i suppose to convert them??

Comment: STORE DATETIME AS DATETIME, NOT AS A STRING IN SOME FANCY FORMAT. Anyway, the solution is to use `STR_TO_DATE(str, format)` to convert your fancy dates to... dates, and compare with `NOW()`.

Comment: If `futureEntry` is a date (or date & time) you should keep it in the database in a field of type [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) (or [`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)), not `VARCHAR`. `CHAR`, `VARCHAR` and `TEXT` data types are for free-form text, not for dates or numbers.